# Connecting to MySQL from R

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am trying to connect to MySQL from R. I have installed "8.0.11 MySQL Community Server - GPL" on my machine. In R studio, I have installed RMySQL Library.

When I give the command:

```
con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),user="root", password = "password", dbname="test")
```

I keep getting the error:

> Error in .local(drv, ...) :  Failed to connect to database: Error:
>   Unknown database 'test'

I am not sure why it keep giving this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Error: Unknown database 'test'.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a code I use for access to MySQL from R

```
# 1. Library
library(RMySQL)

# 2. Settings
db_user <- 'your_name'
db_password <- 'your_password'
db_name <- 'database_name'
db_table <- 'your_data_table'
db_host <- '127.0.0.1' # for local access
db_port <- 3306

# 3. Read data from db
mydb <-  dbConnect(MySQL(), user = db_user, password = db_password,
                 dbname = db_name, host = db_host, port = db_port)
s <- paste0("select * from ", db_table)
rs <- dbSendQuery(mydb, s)
df <-  fetch(rs, n = -1)
on.exit(dbDisconnect(mydb))
```

Please, check how it works on your side.

PS. Looks like you miss 'db_table' parameter.

Comment: andrii I'm sorry as may be here is not the right place to ask but I have issue with connect to mysql using require_ secure_ transport=ON [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/access-mysql-database-from-shinyapps-io-using-require-secure-transport-on/8723/4). If you have any solution may be I can post a another question in SO. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I posted what is work for me. If it's useful please you know what to do here

Comment: Sorry may be my comment wasn't clear. Did you or have you ever try to connect to mysql while defining require_secure_transport=ON in etc/mysql/my.cnf.

Comment: What it the format of the host parameter in case of a remote connection to a Database?

Answer (score 2):

RMariaDB seems to be the way to go these days. Tested with MySQL.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

R code:

```
# install.packages("RMariaDB")
library(DBI)

# Connect to the MySQL database
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), 
             dbname = "test", 
             host = "localhost", 
             port = 3306,
             user = "root",
             password = "password")

# Get table names
tables <- dbListTables(con)

# Display structure of tables
str(tables)

# Always cleanup by disconnecting the database
dbDisconnect(con)
```

You might run into authentication issues:

Error: Failed to connect: Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'TopSecret##1234';
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious reason may be "I hope" beacuse you didn't include the host ip. Also I prefer use `pool` package. Then your connection call may be

```
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
library(pool)

pool <- dbPool(
                  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
                  dbname = "db_name",
                  host = "127.0.0.1",
                  username = 'user_name',
                  password = 'password',
                  port = 3306
             )

 onStop(function() {
           poolClose(pool)
         })
```

Another thing it's better to define user with appropriate privileges on test DB and use this user in the connection call insteade of root as DB connection security best practice.