# How to connect to remote MySQL server via SSH in RStudio 1.2

Tags: mysql, r, odbc, rstudio

I want to connect to a remote MySQL server through SSH in RStudio 1.2 since they announced SQL integration(https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/10/02/rstudio-1-2-preview-sql/).

I can connect to the server using MySQL workbench using standard TCP/IP over SSH with all the SSH and MySQL login info I have. But for RStudio, I didn't have a clear idea where should I put those SSH info.
I find this https://www.r-bloggers.com/accessing-mysql-through-r/ from r bloggers and another question [Connecting to MySQL from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544230/connecting-to-mysql-from-r)
but the both didn't have the SSH part.

My machine 
OS: Windows 10 
R: 3.5.3 
RStudio: 1.2.1335 
RMySQL package installed. 

Remote server 
OS:ubuntu 16.04LTS 
SSH host = myhost.dns.com 
SSH port = 222 
username = user1 
password = password1 
MySQL version: 5.7.26 
MySQL host = 127.0.0.1 
MySQL port = 3306 
MySQL username = user2 
MySQL password = password2

I found some code like this but there is also no SSH part so RStudio will return error.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                        Driver    = "MySQL", 
                        Server    = [My Server],
                        Database  = [My Database],
                        UID       = [My User ID],
                        PWD       = [My Password],
                        Port      = 3306)
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.