# How to connect to MariaDB on NAS and read the data?

Tags: mysql, r, linux, synology, rmariadb

From R running on a Ubuntu machine, I want to connect to a MariaDB living on a Synology NAS and read the table. As the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/r-statistical-programming-using-mariadb-as-the-background-database/) suggests, I do

```
library(RMariaDB)

con <- dbConnect(
  drv=RMariaDB::MariaDB(), 
  username='<user>',
  password='<password>', 
  host='192.168.1.2', 
  port=3307,
  dbname='foo'
)
```

but this just fails with the error:

```
Error: Failed to connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 
 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 110
```

The port is correct since otherwise I get

```
Error: Failed to connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on '
  192.168.1.2:<wrongport>' (111)
```

The driver also appears to be available:

```
RMariaDB::MariaDB()
# <MariaDBDriver>
```

Note, that I already installed [MariaDB Connector/ODBC and UnixODBC](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-odbc/#installing-mariadb-connectorodbc). The database itself is accessible since I am able to connect using RemoDB on Android with the same credentials. Maybe I just missed something basic.

Finally, I would simply like to do this:

```
dat <- dbReadTable(con)
```

*Specs:*

```
Ubuntu:      20.04.3 LTS 
Linux:       5.13.0-27-generic x86_64 
mysql:       8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 

DSM:         7.0.1-42218 
phpMyAdmin:  4.9.7-1032 
MariaDB 10:  10.3.29-1038

R:           4.1.2
RStudio:     2021.9.0.351
RMariaDB:    1.2.1
odbc:        1.3.3
DBI:         1.1.2
```

### Update

I managed to connect to the database **without** using `RMariaDB::MariaDB()` but using `RMySQL::MySQL()` instead<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50544442/6574038)</sup>. **However**, there are two remaining issues:

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60094669/6574038) states, *"RMariaDB will be a replacement for RMySQL, so in near future you will not get bug or security fixes for RMySQL anymore."* Is this really true? What is now the best way to connect to my MariaDB?
2. Establishing the connection takes a **very** long time (see timing below). What could be the issue? I have no clue what could be wrong since there are many steps involved.

```
system.time(
  mydb <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), user=db_user, password=db_password,
                   dbname=db_name, host=db_host, port=db_port)
  )
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.070   0.116 206.902

s <- paste0("select * from ", db_table)
rs <- dbSendQuery(mydb, s)
df <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
on.exit(dbDisconnect(mydb))
```

Comment: you could perhaps try to connect with standard obdc : `drv=odbc::odbc(),Driver = "MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver", Server=...)`. This worked for me on `MariaDB`

Comment: @Waldi Thanks, gives me `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver' : file not found` though. Conversely in terminal I get `odbc-mariadb is already the newest version (3.1.4-1)`. What strikes me is that `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` gives an empty list.

Comment: Did you install https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-odbc/ on the linux computer? This is needed to avoid above error message.

Comment: @Waldi Yes, more precisely I did [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-mariadb-connectorodbc-from-source/). I am not sure if this is an RMariaDB, Ubuntu, Synology, MySQL, a firewall, or whatever problem.